# React Navigation: Share state between two screens within TabNavigator

Tags: react-native, socket.io, react-navigation

I'm learning react native by building a simple chat app. I have two screens wrapped in a TabNavigator where the first screen (Screen A) being the chatbox, and the other screen (Screen B) which displays a list of online users. I'm using SocketIO to fetch these users.

Problem is, how can I access the "onlineUsers" state from ScreenA to ScreenB so I can see an updated list of online users whenever I receive a "user joins" event?

**Screen A:**

```
export default class ScreenA extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      onlineUsers = [];
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // Update list of online users when new user joins chat
    this.socket.on('user joins', (payload) => {
      this.setState({
        onlineUsers: payload.users
      })
    })
  }
}
```

**Screen B:**

```
export default class ScreenB extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    // I want to get the onlineUsers from ScreenA
    this.state = {
      onlineUsers = [];
    }
  }
}
```

**Router:**

```
export const Chat = TabNavigator({
  ChatBox: {
   screen: ScreenA
  },
  OnlineUsers: {
   screen: ScreenB
  },
})
```

PS: I'm using react-navigation to handle navigation

Answer (score 3):

Best way is to handle events in the parent component and then passing it to their children components. So in your case, you should have a online user list in your router. Then pass the array to screen B. Here is how you should do

**Router**

```
state = {
    online_users:[]
}

_update = (data) => {
    this.setState({online_users:data});
};

export const Chat = TabNavigator({
   ChatBox: {
       screen: <ScreenA onUpdate={this._update}/>
    },
    OnlineUsers: {
       screen: <ScreenB userList={this.state.online_users}>
    },
})
```

**Screen A**

```
export default class ScreenA extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        // Update list of online users when new user joins chat
        this.socket.on('user joins', (payload) => {
            this.props.onUpdate(payload.users)
        })
    }
}
```

**Screen B**

```
export default class ScreenB extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    // You can access online user using this.props.userList

 }
```

Comment: Except that `<ScreenA />` is not valid - it will only accept `ScreenA`, which does not allow passing additional props.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this post when I ran into a similar issue earlier this year so I thought I'd post my solution.

I would say your best bet in this situation is to use a Custom Navigator to wrap your TabNavigator which will expose `<TabNavigator />` in your custom navigator allowing you to pass any methods or state down to `ScreenA` and `ScreenB` as `screenProps`.

The custom navigator would look like:

```
import React from 'react'
import { ChatTabNavigator } from './ChatTabNavigator'

class StateManagingCustomNavigator extends React.Component {
  static router = ChatTabNavigator.router

  state = {
    onlineStatus: [theStatus]
  }

  handleMessagePosted = () => {
    // Handle message post, etc...
  }

  // ... SocketIO code and other logic to manage the state here? ...

  render() {
    const { navigation } = this.props
    const { onlineStatus } = this.state

    return (
      <ChatTabNavigator
       screenProps={{
         theStatus: onlineStatus,
         chatMessagePosted: this.handleMessagePosted
       }}
       navigation={navigation}
      />
    )
  }
}

export default StateManagingCustomNavigator
```

From here you could implement an event system as @Ashish Prakash suggested, or manage all of your state in the custom navigator and transform `ScreenA` and `ScreenB` into presentational components.

Answer (score -1):

Use `this.props.navigation.setParam({onlineUsers: onlineUsers: payload.users})` when you get user-list from server.

Then use it in Screen B like `this.props.navigation.state.params.onlineUsers`

Comment: This is false. Those params are only consistent within a single route, not across the two screens. See this snack: https://snack.expo.io/rJvG78XIQ